# What data is used in the following tr34 asn.1 message for the generation of the signature?

Tags: openssl, sha256

I'm trying to validate the signature at the bottom of this message. I have the public key, but I don't know what part of the data is used.

```
-----BEGIN TR34_Sample_UBT_KDH PEM File-----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-----END TR34_Sample_UBT_KDH PEM File-----
```

Comment: never share your key with anyone

Comment: Good point - you should never share your private key with anyone.

Comment: Answer on another thread: [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262612/what-data-is-used-to-calculate-the-sha256-messagedigest-of-this-asn-1-message)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What data is used to calculate the sha256 messagedigest of this asn.1 message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54262612/what-data-is-used-to-calculate-the-sha256-messagedigest-of-this-asn-1-message)

Comment: The other question was what data is used to calculate the message digest. This question is what data do we use to validate the signature. Different parts of the message for each question.

Answer (score 0):

TR-34 messages such as the KDH unbind token are really just Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) messages but it is a fairly complicated standard, probably too complex to explain in a stack overflow answer.

The specification for CMS can be found here: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5652

Specifically see section 5.4 Message Digest Calculation Process

Take a look at the BouncyCastle implementation of `SignSignerInformation#doVerify` at https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/main/pkix/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/cms/SignerInformation.java#L353 to see how the digest is computed using the DER encoded data.

There is also an open source project that demonstrates the crafting and verification of TR 34 messages using Bouncy Castle that you can find here: https://github.com/clover/clover-tr34-host

You might consider walking through the tests with a debugger to see how Bouncy Castle does the verification in precise detail.

Note that some of the TR-34 sample messages appear to be malformed, this is mentioned in the Clover TR 34 test methods.